# MVC FindView slow on application start

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, performance, asp.net-mvc-views

Is there anyway to run through the application and pre-populate the MVC ViewCache to eliminate the 2sec time loss that can sometimes occur during the warm-up of a web app?

At current whilst our application is starting, we sometimes are greeted with 2sec performance lag times.. once it's started there are mere-milliseconds.

In case it helps, I am definitely running in release mode, and only use the Razor engine:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        Bootstrapper.Initialise(); //IOC Setup
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //Only use the RazorEngine. - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/08/16/optimizing-mvc-view-lookup-performance.aspx
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();

        IViewEngine razorEngine = new RazorViewEngine() { FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" } };

        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(razorEngine);
    }
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Ta

Comment: On which version of IIS are you hosting your application?

Comment: It doesn't matter - read D. Ward's article mentioned below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the new ASP.NET [AutoStart feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) in IIS 7.5. Also make sure that when you deploy your application it is running in Release mode (`debug="false"`).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this, but strangely things aren't as instant as you'd expect (that could be another issue).

Comment: You could bring that a step further by writing a custom `IProcessHostPreloadClient` provider as shown in the ScottGu's post inside which you could do heavy initialization work and warmup the application.

Comment: I thought about that, but is there anyway to iterate all the views and load them all...

Answer (score 1):

Dave Ward discusses this and other issues related to debug="false" in your web.config in [A harsh reminder about the importance of debug=”false”](http://encosia.com/a-harsh-reminder-about-the-importance-of-debug-false/).

> In debug mode, view resolution is optimized for ease of development.
>   MVC iterates through the view resolution process each and every time
>   your code renders a named view. That’s helpful since you obviously do
>   want the environment to respond immediately to your changes when
>   you’re working on a site.
>
> In release mode, however, MVC’s view resolution is optimized for
>   performance. When a view location is successfully resolved in release
>   mode, MVC caches the result of that lookup and doesn’t need to perform
>   another filesystem search when it encounters a reference to that named
>   view again.

Comment: Thanks - Don't worry, I've read over the @SamSaffron blog post about views being slow, and I've included my very own "Big Pink Box(TM)" method which checks for Http debugging etc.. so I know we're running in 'Release'/Retail mode

Comment: Thanks for that - that's all good and well, but it's the FIRST view lookup that is the problem

Comment: Based on your updated question, you've already done all that I know of to optimize view location. If there are other options, I'd like to know as well!

Comment: Darin's answer regarding AutoStart looks promising.

Comment: I'm thinking about writing a quick and dirty bit of code that will iterate the views folder and call render on the views (hopefully). I'll try share if I can!